# Can you have overlapping binding areas in knockout

Tags: knockout.js

Say I was creating something like the windows desktop with markup such as:

```
<div id="os">
   <div id="desktop"></div>
   <div id="taskbar"></div>
</div>
```

and then bind it like this:

```
ko.applyBindings(vm, $("#os")[0]);
```

If I then inject this new markup into the desktop div:

```
<div id="newWidget">
   ...
</div>
```

and call

```
ko.applyBindings(vm2, $("#newWidget")[0]);
```

to bind the new markup to an entirely different view model, is that going to be problematic?

What if any problems might this kind of overlapping binding areas cause?

Comment: Sure you can, but I personally wouldn't recommend it. http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/05/quick-tip-skip-binding.html

Comment: @Jeff: The answer seems more like no, but you can block the scope of a parent binding somewhat. The article you linked is very helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of inserting the HTML like that use the powerfull template engine. 
It can be done in many ways, with the standard engine you need to insert the templatge as a script tag and then used like

```
<div data-bind="foreach: widgets">
   <!-- ko template: { name: view, data: $data } --><!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

Above solution needs a member `view` with the template name. This creates a coupling between VM and View, plus the template syntax is messy.

I've created a library called Knockout.BindingConventions, its a implicit library that favors conventions over explicit configurations. One of its features is to connect ViewModels to views. The html would look something like this

```
<div data-name="widgets">
   <!-- ko name: $data --><!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

If the array of widgets contain a `CalendarWidgetViewModel` it will look for a `CalendarWidgetView` template, if it also constains a `ContactsWidgetViewModel` it will look for a `ContactsWidgetView` template.

[Wiki](https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/Knockout.BindingConventions/wiki/Template-convention)

Install using nuge

```
Install-Package Knockout.BindingConventions
```

Above solutions require you to have templates as script tags

There are external template source engines that load templates on demand with ajax.

For example https://github.com/ifandelse/Knockout.js-External-Template-Engine

I've made my own that uses above convention library

[Wiki](https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/Knockout.Bootstrap/wiki)

Once configured (You need to create a rest service that handels the template requests)
its just a matter of doing `bootstrap.loadView(model, this.view);`

It will look at the model type resolve its view name, take all views for that ViewModel either from cache or server.